# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Java 8 Amazon Linux Platform Version 2.11 Idle Timeout Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to run Java 8 App and i have a long running job that that takes around 5 minutes to finish.
After 1 minute mark, it seems that the connection stops and i get 504 Gateway Timeout. I did some research on this and it seems i need to change the Idle Timeout to a bigger value. I dont want to change it manually, but instead i want to change it via script or something.
Right now i have `.ebextensions\nginx\conf.d\proxy.conf` file where i have  the following values

```
proxy_connect_timeout       600s;
proxy_send_timeout          600s;
proxy_read_timeout          600s;
send_timeout                600s;
```

So here are my questions:

1. Do i need to have those values in the `proxy.conf` file?
2. How can i set this `Idle Timeout` value in a config file?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: If a job takes that long to complete - why not look at writing a workflow using AWS Step Functions and invoke that from your Spring App.

Comment: that is an option, or either to spin up a separate thread to do the job and notify with email after that, but i want to keep it sync.